# For two positive operators on Hilbert space is it true that $A \ge B \implies \|A\| \ge \|B\|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

$H$ is Hilbert space. $A$ and $B$ is positive linear operators from $H$ to $H$ i.e. $\forall x\in H\, (Ax,x),\,(Bx,x)\ge 0$. $A\ge B$ means that $A-B$ is positive. Does that means that $\|A\| \ge \|B\|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  For a positive linear operator $A$, $\|A\| = \sup \{(Ax, x): \; \|x\| = 1\}$.  If $A \ge B$, $(Ax, x) \ge (Bx, x)$, so we must have $\|A\| \ge \|B\|$.